# Why can I not import tensorflow into my Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, tensorflow2.0

I have run a simple neural network through pycharm, pointing it to a conda virtual environment with tensorflow and dependencies installed. When I launch a jupyter notebook from that same env the exact code aborts when I try and import tensorflow.

This is the code at the top of the notebook:

`import tensorflow as tf`

`from tensorflow import keras`
`.....`

I expected tensorflow and keras to load ok.

Instead I got:
`` `--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ``
`ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)`
`<ipython-input-3-2be7691b079e> in <module>`
`----> 1 import tensorflow as tf`
`2 from tensorflow import keras`
`...`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`

I added a line to list installed modules at the top of the notebook in case it was looking somewhere without tensorflow installed :

`!conda list`
`` ` ``

And got:

```
# packages in environment at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf-cert:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
......
cudnn                     8.2.1                cuda11.3_0  
.....
keras                     2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
libclang                  14.0.6                   pypi_0    pypi
libedit                   3.1.20210910         h7f8727e_0  
.......

scipy                     1.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                65.5.0           py38h06a4308_0  
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.33.0               h62c20be_0  
tensorboard               2.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-datasets       4.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.28.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metadata       1.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem while using VS Code. I had created a virtual environment using `venv`, but when I selected that environment, I wasn't able to import any libraries even though I had installed all the required ones.

I simply deleted the environment and created a new one using -
`conda create --prefix ./env pandas numpy ...` in the terminal/command prompt. I then restarted VS Code and selected this particular environment. That fixed the issue. The python version and the library versions need to be in sync with each other to work properly. Hope this works for you too.

Edit:

I was again facing the same problem when I created a new environment. I then selected the python environment where I had installed the Tensorflow library from the top right corner in Jupyter notebook (underlined red). That solved the issue!

[image]

Comment: This is such a weird error that I believe your solution could work. I'll try it if all else fails..